# Formal proof of correctness of Levenshtein distance

Tags: proof-assistants, edit-distance

Has anyone formalized, in a proof assistant (constructively!) the correctness of the computation of [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) ? The [related Q&A](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/proof-of-levenshtein-distance) on here is about paper proofs.  Searching around did not come up with any leads.

Note that I'm equally interested in correctness as that of a proof of optimality, i.e. knowing that an algorithm returns a correct sequence of edits, from which the distance is trivially computed, is quite interesting too. That the sequence is optimal can be a second step.

Comment: Have you seen https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8664354?

Comment: I had not, thanks. This leads to https://manau.jp/Lean/cotoleta/ as a place where I can download a Lean formalization.

Comment: @Tyilo your comment should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in a comment above, the answer is yes, in Lean.  See the paper and the code as linked into comments.

I was rather hoping Agda or Idris... but perhaps the Lean formalization is actually constructive.

Comment: I can't imagine they managed to make it non-constructive...